# In postgres INSERT .. ON CONFLICT can I have both a column and a where clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to build a SQL statement that allows for an upsert but does not do an update if a sequence number is older than the current value.  The use case is retrieving events from a stream that might be out of order, so I want to ignore those if the sequence number in the row is greater than the one I'm trying to update. The SQL currently looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO events (
  uuid,
  event_id,
  event_type,
  . . .
  last_sequence_number
) VALUES (
  $1,
  $2,
  $3,
  . . .,
  $10
) ON CONFLICT (uuid) DO
UPDATE SET
  event_id = $2,
  event_type = $3,
  . . . ,
  last_sequence_number = $10
WHERE last_sequence_number IS NULL OR last_seequence_number < $10
RETURNING *;
```

The desired result is:

1. row is inserted if the uuid has not been seen,
2. row is upserted with new values if the last_sequence_number on the row is less than the new value.

The error I'm getting is `ERROR: column reference "last_sequence_number" is ambiguous (SQLSTATE 42702)` and I'm not sure if I've just got something in the wrong place or if it is not possible the way I'm intending in postgresql 15.

Comment: I would  try `WHERE events.last_sequence_number IS NULL OR events.last_sequence_number < $10`.

Comment: I think that was it! I just needed to be more explict. Thank you!

Comment: I haven't tested but I'm thinking this is needed to deal with the special table `excluded` that is built for  the ON CONFLICT and may hold the same values.

Comment: As a general rule, qualify column identifiers in SQL queries except where they are used as an assignment target in a `SET` clause.